Guest users are unable to view other users in the Global Search feature within the CMS Experience Cloud
I am unable to search for community users when logged out from the community page and attempting to use global search as a guest user.

I am able to see the search results when I am logged in though.
Guest users can see the rest of content, but not "People"
Does someone know how it can be solved?


Both settings are enabled.

Strikes me as appropriate behaviour from a security and privacy perspective.
